# Simple SQL GROUP BY

Tags: sql

I have a table named `foobar` with columns `name` and `location`. I want use SQL to get all the names of people that have been to New York but have not been to San Francisco.

So far have:

```
  select name 
    from foobar 
   where location = "New York" and location != "San Francisco" 
group by name
```

Comment: I assume each row is a visit to a location by a name. So if I went to both NY and SF, there would be 2 DaveShaw's, one at each location? A sample of the table data might help clear this up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT f.name
    FROM foobar f
    WHERE f.location = 'New York'
        AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                           FROM foobar f2
                           WHERE f2.name = f.name
                               AND f2.location = 'San Francisco')
```

You could also do this with a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT f.name
    FROM foobar f
        LEFT JOIN foobar f2
            ON f.name = f2.name
                AND f2.location = 'San Francisco'
    WHERE f.location = 'New York'
        AND f2.name IS NULL
```

Answer (score 5):

```
select name 
from foobar 
where location = "New York"
and name not in (select name 
from foobar 
where location = "San Francisco")
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, SQL "not exists" query comes in handy. Have a look at the following query:

```
select f1.name 
from foobar as f1 
where f1.location = "New York" 
and not exists
    (select f2.name 
     from foobar as f2
     where f1.name= f2.name
     and location = "San Francisco")
```

For better understanding, let's break this query into smaller parts.

Part-1:
Let's say, this is query1

```
  select f1.name
  from foobar as f1
  where f1.location = "New York"
```

This simple select query will display all the names which have visited New York. Simple as that!

Part-2:
Let's say, this is query2

```
  select f2.name
  from foobar as f2
  where f2.location = "San Francisco"
```

This is another simple select query which will display all the names which have visited San Francisco.

Now what we need to achieve is that, we want the names of those who visited New York, MINUS the names who have visited San Francisco. Now it might happen that a person has visited both New York and San Francisco, hence we are eliminating those people. We want only the New York visitors. So we are actually discarding query2's results from the query1, combining like this:

```
  query1
  and not exists
  (query2 + where f1.name = f2.name)
```

or,

```
 select f1.name
 from foobar as f1
 where f1.location = "New York"
 and not exists
 (select f2.name
  from foobar as f2
  where f1.name = f2.name
  and f2.location = "San Francisco")
```